# Cannot use the class accessed from another file in same directory in python

Tags: python, class, module, python-module

I defined a class in try.py

**try.py**

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name, major, gpa, is_on_probation):
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation
```

Now i created new file in same directory. `class.py`

**class.py**

```
from try import student

student1 = student("Jimmy", "Business", 3.1, False)
print(student1.name)
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/test/try.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**PROBLEM**

The print statement does not produce any result.
I'm new to both python and stack overflow. I searched and couldn't find a solution. So I'm posting this.

Comment: `try` and `class` are reserved keyword, thus it will result in a syntax error.  Please rename `try.py` and `class.py` to a different name to avoid this issue.  Also, running what you currently named as `try.py` produce no output because it only defined a class `student` and immediately exit.

Answer (score 2):

You're not *running* the program that prints things. You're running `try.py` as a script. You need to run `class.py` (and you also need to pick better file names, because you've picked two names that are both keywords, preventing use of `import`).